# Open source projects using OpenUI5 or more SAPUI5/OpenUI5 demo applications

Tags: javascript, architecture, sapui5

I am trying to develop custom ERP-type application using OpenUI5 and Zend web services.

1. Are there any open source projects which use OpenUI5 or are there more demo applications?
2. I am trying to understand tdg (Application Best practices) demo application. As far as I can understand then the whole application is made as a one component and that is why the single controller of the application is so minimal. But is it the right approach - create whole application as component?
3. I guess - application should have many parts and each part should have its separate controller and set of views. Are there demo application available which has more than one controller. I am aware of the documentation, e.g. developer guide and walkthrough tutorial, but maybe there are other good resources for starting serious application?

Answer (score 2):

First of all please try to structure your question a bit more and try to provide more detail. This will make answering the question easier.

1. Not sure about this. For me just working off the official/generic documentation worked just fine so I never searched for more.
2. Yes and no. A component is defined by being independent and reusable.

   Indepentend: This means that the component is fully functional on its own and can be used without relying on sorrounding implementations.

   Reusable: Well, this just means that a component can be reused in other applications to bundle/provide some functionality.

   On that note an application could not use the component concept at all, be exactly one component, or even contain several different components to use their functoniality. That being best practice would be to encapsulate every app in at least one top level component since that will make it independent from the html it is embedded in. Also if you want to use the app in the fiori launchpad it has to be encapsulated in a component.

   So in the end: *Yes, an application should be created inside a component.*
3. Did you see [this](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/b4/d66ebee72645c1a3501a769e935541/content.htm?frameset=/en/b4/d66ebee72645c1a3501a769e935541/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/5c/be4e5b4a19479a92b1d32ff23b7b63/plain.htm&node_id=48&show_children=true#jump48) already? It outlines an applications encapsulated in a component but using multiple views, fragments and controllers. I think it might contain the answer to a lot of your questions and building it will give insight in some of the concepts.

Comment: Point 3 - exactly what I needed - to understand this sample application. Thanks!